# S=(0,1] Open Cover and Finite Subcover

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,0<x\leq1\}$. Give an example of an open cover of $S$ that has a finite subcover. Also, show that $S$ is not compact by giving an example of an open cover that does not admit a finite subcover. Justify your answer.

Can anyone help me with this? Please explain the intuition of finding it too.

Thank you so much!

Comment: $\{S\}$ is an open cover of itself that has a finite subcover I'll let you answer the second part yourself

Comment: For the second part, try to abuse that 0 is a limit point of $S$, which is not contained in $S$. So, choose your covering sets centered around 0, in such a way that all of them are necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial cover with a finite subcover, is any cover that's finite to begin with, so $\{(0,2)\}$ (if we cover with open sets of $\Bbb R$) or $\{S\}$ if we cover by open sets of $S$ itself; it doesn't matter for the definition of compactness of a subspace which type we use).

One without a finite subcover: $\{(\frac{1}{n}, 1]\}_{n \in \Bbb N^+}$ or $\{(\frac{1}{n}, 2)\}_{n \in \Bbb N^+}$, depending on taste. In a finite subfamily a maximal $n$ is used and then $\frac{1}{n+1}$ for that $n$ cannot be covered. So no finite subcover exists.